# Pass arguments to Zope browser page

Tags: python, parameter-passing, zope

In my Zope instance, I have a Python script registered as a browser page.  I have the following code as its registry:

`<browser:page name="test" for="*" permission="zope2.Public" class="browser.test.PyTest" attribute="CallPy" />`

This function, "PyTest.CallPy" is defined as:

`def CallPy(self, data): ...`

I then use JavaScript to call the function, passing data in:

`$.ajax({ url: "@@test", data: ({data: "mydata"}), dataType: "text", success: ..., error: ... });`

However, when I make this call, I get an error that says "CallPy() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)".

How do I register this function as a page that passes in this data when it is called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing rather a lot of detail on your method.  Is it a method of a class? Or standalone?  Normally, **self** would refer to an instance of the class **PyTest** - which would be a subclass of **BrowserView**.

Then, the data you pass to the view (**@@test**) is retrieved from the **Request** object, which is available in **self.request** (specifically, in this case, **self.request.form.data**) (So, you don't specify a 'data' argument to the method).

hmmm.  I don't think you want the parentheses around the dict in: `data: ({data: "mydata"})`.

Comment: The parentheses are in the JavaScript code and make no difference in this case. Zope will un-marshall the request parameters and match them to the method signature, so CallPy should be passed a 'data' parameter from the GET request, if everything was set up correctly.

Comment: Also, in the Python script, you would access the sent in data like any other dictionary:  `self.request.form['data']`